# ffmpeg command produces black image as output

Tags: ffmpeg, ip-camera

Input #0, video4linux2,v4l2, from '/dev/video0':

Duration: N/A, start: 13555.753906, bitrate: 147456 kb/s

```
Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (YUY2 / 0x32595559), yuyv422, 640x480, 147456 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 1000k tbn, 1000k tbc
```

Stream mapping:

Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (rawvideo (native) -> mjpeg (native))

Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[swscaler @ 0x55fd0eafa3e0] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
Output #0, image2, to 'test1.jpeg':

Metadata:

```
encoder         : Lavf57.83.100

Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj422p(pc), 640x480, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbn, 30 tbc

Metadata:

  encoder         : Lavc57.107.100 mjpeg

Side data:

  cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/200000 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
```

frame=    1 fps=0.0 q=1.6 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:00.03 bitrate=N/A speed=8.41x

video:3kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown

Comment: [Edit] your question with a link to the output image.

Comment: COMMAND i used : ffmpeg  -i /dev/video0 -vframes 1 test1.jpeg


it produces black jpeg image as output? why ?
please suggest ffmpeg command to get webcam image?

Comment: *"it produces black jpeg image as output? why ?"* I don't know why. That's what I'm trying to find out. *"please suggest ffmpeg command to get webcam image?"* Your command looks correct.